# What type is INTERVAL in the function DATEPART?

Tags: sql-server, types, datepart

The code `select DATEPART(month,getutcdate())` returns an integer representing the numeric month value of the current date.
The value `MONTH` is one of a number of predefined options for the interval parameter.
What is the underlying data type of that interval value?

```
declare @date datetime = getutcdate()
, @interval notNVarChar(16) = 'month' --what type should this be?  
                                      --Would it need quotes for assignment?

select DATEPART(@interval, @date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one - you cannot parameterize it.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

```
DATEPART ( datepart , date )
```

> *datepart*
>
> Is the part of date (a date or time value) for which an integer will be returned. The following table lists all valid datepart arguments. **User-defined variable equivalents are not valid.**

(my **emphasis**)

Answer (score 3):

You can make it parameterize by making a dynamic SQL as below:

```
declare @date datetime
set @date = GETDATE()
declare @option varchar(50)
declare @sql varchar(max)
SET @option = 'MONTH' --Here you can set other options like hour, second, milisecond etc..

set @sql = 'SELECT DATEPART('+ @option + ',''' + CONVERT(varchar,@date,21)+''')'


print @sql
EXEC( @sql)
```

Comment: Hey @RohitVyas; I would do, but I've already given Damien the answer (and only allowed to accept one per question).  Since his answer's the official line whilst yours is a (great) workaround I figured it's best to give him the answer and you an upvote.  I'd give you both answers if I could though.

Comment: Hi @JohnLBevan,
No problem, I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options available like :

```
day
week
hour
minute
second
millisecond
```

etc..

PLease go thru this[LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)